# handsontable - save initial data

Tags: jquery, handsontable

I am using the handsontable .9 plugin.

I have data that writes a nested list to an off-margin "hidden" field after change working fine:

```
afterChange: function () { $(\"#dt_1\").val(JSON.stringify($container.data(\"handsontable\").getData()));}


<textarea name="F0" cols="150" rows="2" id="dt_1" readonly="readonly" style="float: left; margin-left:-99999px; "></textarea></div>
```

However, when i come back to this page, I have the data re-rendering back in the handsontable, however, the 'change' event is not triggering.
I understand that this afterChange event does not fire for initial load for performance issues.

So, what does?  I need to populate my field that will post upon load complete of the data engine.  My back end system populates the javascript on-page for var data = [[]];

I've tried to use the same function on the following events:

```
afterInit ()
afterLoadData ()
afterRender ()
```

and a few others that sounded logical and they did not work. My textarea does not get updated until i 'focus&blur off' a field.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving the textarea above the grid and it seems to fire correctly now...  So, order of operations error.   I figured the dom on load would fire after the actual html would print out, but i guess not.